# How do I get DOUBLE_MAX?

Tags: c, double

AFAIK, C supports just a few data types:

```
int, float, double, char, void enum.
```

I need to store a number that could reach into the high 10 digits.  Since I'm getting a low 10 digit # from

> INT_MAX

, I suppose I need a double.

`<limits.h>` doesn't have a `DOUBLE_MAX`.  I found a `DBL_MAX` on the internet that said this is LEGACY and also appears to be C++.  Is double what I need?  Why is there no `DOUBLE_MAX`?

Comment: 1) As others pointed out, you don't need a `double`, you need a 64-bit integral type (either `long long`, or `uint64_t`).  2) If you do use a `double`, you don't need `DBL_MAX` (which is the largest number that can be stored), you need [`DBL_DIG`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/float.html#DBL_DIG), which is the number of significant digits you can store. (It won't do you any good to be able to store 9999999999 if you can't distinguish it from 9999999998). In any event, on most systems, a `double` can precisely store all integers of the size you are asking for.

Comment: On most systems, a double can precisely store all postive integers less than 9007199254740993.

Comment: C has many types: `char, unsigned char, signed char, short, unsigned short, int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long, float, double, long double, void`, enums, structs, functions, arrays, and pointers to all of these.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`DBL_MAX` is defined in [`<float.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/float.h.html). Its availability in [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/limits.h.html) on unix is what is marked as "(LEGACY)".

(linking to the unix standard even though you have no unix tag since that's probably where you found the "LEGACY" notation, but much of what is shown there for float.h is also in the C standard back to C89)

Comment: I suspect the "LEGACY" came from some C++ site that wants you to use their arcane std numeric limits system instead of macros because "macros are dirty" or such...

Comment: As I said, the only place I've seen it tagged LEGACY was in a unix standard that was talking about _its presence in limits.h_ rather than DBL_MAX as a whole

Answer (score 67):

You get the *integer* limits in `<limits.h>` or `<climits>`. Floating point characteristics are defined in `<float.h>` for C. In C++, the preferred version is usually `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` (for which you `#include <limits>`).

As to your original question, if you want a larger integer type than `long`, you should probably consider `long long`. This isn't officially included in C++98 or C++03, but is part of C99 and C++11, so all reasonably current compilers support it.

Comment: vs2012 complained without having the brackets i.e: std::numeric_limits<double>::max().  did try a quick edit of the ans but the edit was too small.

Comment: and for the minimum, the counterpart `min` is tricky (it is positive number for double type): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min, so `numeric_limits<double>::lowest()` is more predictable: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest

Answer (score 12):

Its in the standard float.h include file. You want `DBL_MAX`

Answer (score 9):

Using `double` to store large integers is dubious; the largest integer that can be stored reliably in `double` is much smaller than `DBL_MAX`. You should use `long long`, and if that's not enough, you need your own arbitrary-precision code or an existing library.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `float.h` header.

Answer (score 3):

`INT_MAX` is just a definition in [limits.h](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Limits.h). You don't make it clear whether you need to store an integer or floating point value.  If integer, and using a 64-bit compiler, use a `LONG` (`LLONG` for 32-bit).