# value of variable in c language with 100 digits

Tags: c, types, range

So I'm new to c , and I have just learned about data type, what confuse me is that a value range of a double for example is from 2.3E-308 to 1.7E+308
mathematically a number of 100 digits ∈ [2.3E-308 , 1.7E+308].
Writing this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double c = 5416751717547457918597197587615765157415671579185765176547645735175197857989185791857948797847984848;   
printf("%le",c);
return 0;
}
```

the result is 7.531214e+18   by changing %le by %lf th result is 7531214226330737664.000000 
which doesn't equal c.
So whats is the problem.

Comment: Varies from machine, and that is def. way over the limit of a double.

Comment: You get the integer limits in <limits.h> or <climits>. Floating point characteristics are defined in <float.h> for C. In C++, the preferred version is usually std::numeric_limits<double>::max() (for which you #include <limits>). from this site:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834635/how-do-i-get-double-max might help you out

Comment: Understand the difference between **range** and **significance**. A `double` represents a (usually) approximate value with about 16 significant decimal digits. Floating point variables have a significand, a power of 2, and a sign.

Comment: The constant is an integer, which gets truncated before conversion. Add a `.0` to it.

Comment: You've got way more than one confusion here.

Answer (score 3):

This long number is actually a numerical literal of type `long long`. But since this type cannot contain such a long number, it is truncated modulo `(LLONG_MAX + 1)` and resulting in `7531214226330737360`.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/R6Naex).

**Edit:**

@JohnBollinger: ... and then converted to double, with a resulting loss of a few (binary) digits of precision.

@rici: [Demo2](https://ideone.com/73tgiP) - here the constant is of type `double` because of added decimal point

Comment: ... and then converted to `double`, with a resulting loss of a few (binary) digits of precision.

Comment: With warnings turned on, you should have gotten "integer constant too large for its type", then you would have seen that you needed to make it a double constant by adding the `.0`.

Answer (score 1):

It might seem that, if we can store a number of up to 10 to the power 308, we are storing 308 digits or so but, in floating point arithmetic, that isn't the case. Floating point numbers are not stored as huge strings of digits.

Broadly, a floating-point number is stored as a mantissa -- typically a number between zero and one -- and an exponent -- some number raised to the power of some other number. The different kinds of floating point number (float, double, long double) each has a different number of bits allocated to the mantissa and exponent. These bit counts, particularly in the mantissa, control the precision with which the number can be represented.

A double on most platforms gives 16-17 decimal digits of precision, regardless of the magnitude (power of ten). It's possible to use libraries that will do arithmetic to any degree of precision required, although such features are not built into C.

An additional complication is that, in your example, the number you assign to `c` is not actually defined to be a floating point number at all. Lacking any indication that it should be so represented, the compiler will treat it as an integer and, as it's too large to fit even the largest integer type on most platforms, it gets truncated down to integer range.

Comment: All true, but not his problem. His problem was no decimal point, so the compiler tries to read the number as an integer, truncates it to 64 bits, and then converts to double.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I wrote "the compiler will treat it as an integer and..." ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should get a proper compiler or enable warnings on it. A recent GCC, with just default settings will output the following warning:

```
% gcc float.c
float.c: In function ‘main’:
float.c:4:12: warning: integer constant is too large for its type
 double c = 5416751717547457918597197587615765157415671579185765176547645735175197857989185791857948797847984848;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Notice that it says **integer**, i.e. a whole number, not floating point. In C a constant of that form denotes an integer. Unless suffixed with `U`, it is additionally a *signed* integer, of the greatest type that it fits. However, neither standard C, nor common implementations, have a type that is big enough to fit this value. So what happens, is [(C11 6.4.4.1p6)[http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p6])  :

> If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list and has no extended integer type, **then the integer constant has no type.**

Use of such an integer constant without type in arithmetic leads to **undefined behaviour**, that is the whole execution of the program is now meaningless. You should have read the warnings.

The "fix" would have been to add a `.` after the number!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double c = 54167517175474579185971975876157651574156715791\
85765176547645735175197857989185791857948797847984848.;
    printf("%le\n",c);
}
```

And running it:

```
% ./a.out
5.416752e+99
```

Notice that even then, a `double` is precise to average ~15 significant decimal digits only.

Comment: THANKS for answer, I wonder how to print the full number not in scientific notation? thank you again.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand the difference between
"54167517175474579185...................8797847984848"
and
"54167517175474579185...................8797847984848." with that ". "at the end. For me they are the same number .
I'm new to c thanks for your time