# How to define constant in floating point double precision in c89

Tags: c, ieee-754, c89

I have code with a constant declared in a representation that is not valid in c89 (compiler option on historic project).

```
#define K_MAX_KCG_REAL 0x1.FFFFFFFFFFFFFp1023
```

I am looking for a solution valid in c89

I have tried

```
#define K_MAX_KCG_REAL 0x7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

but is is interpreted as an integer with a float value of approx. 9.22e18.
Far from 1.79e308 that I need.
What is the best way to declare a coonstant with max value for double precision ?

Comment: Use type-punning, possibly through a union or a byte buffer? Or why not translate it to the actual `double` value it represents?

Comment: There is a macro DBL_MAX defined in <float.h> :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834635/how-do-i-get-double-max

Comment: Basically the best way is to ditch that compiler. Or ditch that job. Perhaps even in reverse order! C99 is *only* 20 years old!

Comment: thanks for the link but this is critical embedded code, I can't add external header files

Answer (score 2):

The number you are looking for is `179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.`

If `DBL_MAX` is defined in `<float.h>`, you should use that.

With many compilers, `1.7976931348623157e308` would suffice.

If the compiler fails to parse those correctly, you could try `(9007199254740991. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 1073741824. * 2048.)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a union containing a `unsigned long long` and a `double` and initialize the former.

```
const union {
    unsigned long long i;
    double d;
} K_MAX_KCG_REAL = { 0x7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF };
```

Comment: `unsigned long long` would be a non-standard, extended type in c89/c90 though.

Comment: I don't think `unsigned long long` is standard per C89.  It's mentioned as an extension under [**A.6.5 Common extensions**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html).